# Atom packages trouble

Tags: package

I was trying to browse for https//atom.io/packages but however i cannot get into the website. Moreover while i am trying to download packages from atom it shows "Searching for 'packageName' failed" . Can anyone tell me if the server is down or in maintenance . Off course there might be problem from my location . At this moment i cannot figure it out. Please let me know what i should do now.

Package install trouble

[image: 1]

Comment: https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/ "Atom package management will stop working"

Answer (score 0):

github is sunsetting atom... Atom package management will stop working